# Apache NiFi "ExecuteSQL" Querying with Join in Oracle Database does not work

Tags: oracle, ojdbc, apache-nifi

I try to retrieve the joined content of two tables in an Oracle Database with a very easy SQL query:

```
SELECT OWNER.CONTENT.ID, OWNER.CONTENT.TITLE, OWNER.BODYCONTENT.BODY
FROM OWNER.CONTENT, OWNER.BODYCONTENT
WHERE OWNER.CONTENT.ID = OWNER.BODYCONTENT.ID 
AND OWNER.CONTENT.ID < 7
```

The query runs using Oracle SQL Developer.

I am using the ojdbc7.jar driver in NiFi. Simpler SQL queries not containing a join work with "ExecuteSQL", e. g.

```
SELECT OWNER.CONTENT.ID, OWNER.CONTENT.TITLE
FROM OWNER.CONTENT
WHERE OWNER.CONTENT.ID < 7
```

I have also tried other SQL statements (e. g. INNER JOIN). The queries work as expected using Oracle SQL Developer but not in NiFi. Can someone help me?

ERROR Message in NiFi:

> 2016-05-03 11:30:02,413 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-6]
>   o.a.nifi.processors.standard.ExecuteSQL 
>   org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException:
>   java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: Unsupported feature     at
>   org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ExecuteSQL$1.process(ExecuteSQL.java:160)
>   ~[nifi-standard-processors-0.6.1.jar:0.6.1]   at
>   org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.StandardProcessSession.write(StandardProcessSession.java:1954)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ExecuteSQL.onTrigger(ExecuteSQL.java:152)
>   ~[nifi-standard-processors-0.6.1.jar:0.6.1]   at
>   org.apache.nifi.processor.AbstractProcessor.onTrigger(AbstractProcessor.java:27)
>   [nifi-api-0.6.1.jar:0.6.1]    at
>   org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1059)
>   [nifi-framework-core-0.6.1.jar:0.6.1]     at
>   org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.call(ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.java:136)
>   [nifi-framework-core-0.6.1.jar:0.6.1]     at
>   org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.call(ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.java:47)
>   [nifi-framework-core-0.6.1.jar:0.6.1]     at
>   org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:123)
>   [nifi-framework-core-0.6.1.jar:0.6.1]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>   [na:1.7.0_60]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304)
>   [na:1.7.0_60]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
>   [na:1.7.0_60]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
>   [na:1.7.0_60]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>   [na:1.7.0_60]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>   [na:1.7.0_60]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_60]
>   Caused by: java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: Unsupported
>   feature   at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.ClobAccessor.getBytes(ClobAccessor.java:534)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.GeneratedStatement.getBytes(GeneratedStatement.java:151)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.GeneratedScrollableResultSet.getBytes(GeneratedScrollableResultSet.java:326)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet.getBytes(DelegatingResultSet.java:241)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet.getBytes(DelegatingResultSet.java:241)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.util.JdbcCommon.convertToAvroStream(JdbcCommon.java:105)
>   ~[nifi-standard-processors-0.6.1.jar:0.6.1]   at
>   org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.util.JdbcCommon.convertToAvroStream(JdbcCommon.java:72)
>   ~[nifi-standard-processors-0.6.1.jar:0.6.1]   at
>   org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ExecuteSQL$1.process(ExecuteSQL.java:158)
>   ~[nifi-standard-processors-0.6.1.jar:0.6.1]   ... 14 common frames
>   omitted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like one of your return columns is either BINARY, VARBINARY, LONGVARBINARY, ARRAY, BLOB , or CLOB, and when NiFi gets the value for this column it calls ResultSet getBytes(i) and in the Oracle Driver that eventually calls a method that throws a not supported exception.

I created this JIRA:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-1841

Not totally sure what the solution will be since we have to rely on the JDBC interface, and if a specific database driver doesn't support something that we rely on then we can only do so much.

Comment: Bryan, Clobs have to be read differently, only a few drivers support getBytes(). See e.g. this old, but applicable example. The same applies to Blobs, too http://blog.mclaughlinsoftware.com/java-programming/how-to-read-a-clob-through-jdbc/

Comment: Thanks Andrew. It seems like this block of code where it uses getBytes for all of those types would really need to be split into using the specific getClob() , getBlob(), etc. and hopefully most drivers end up supporting those.

https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/e4b7e47836edf47042973e604005058c28eed23b/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-standard-bundle/nifi-standard-processors/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/processors/standard/util/JdbcCommon.java#L103